# gremlin order by query with incr

Tags: java, cassandra, sql-order-by, gremlin, tinkerpop3

```
g.V().has(label,"request_job").order().by("submit_time",incr).valueMap("submit_time")

==>[submit_time:[1330647978000]]
==>[submit_time:[1330652298000]]
```

When I use, order() query in Gremlin console, it is working fine. But when I try the same query in Java, I am not able to use "incr", it is showing that `undefined symbol "incr"`.

How to use "incr" with order() in Java?

Kindly help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is defined in the enum `Order` ([javadoc](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.2.4/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/Order.html#incr)) which is automatically imported by the Gremlin Console. You should add the following import to your Java class:

```
import static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Order.*;
```